# zsh: Is it possible to implement a `local export`?

Tags: zsh, environment-variables

Is it possible to implement a `local export` in zsh? Possibly using try and always?

Does this create race-conditions?

By "local export", I mean something exactly like a local variable, that is accessible to the subprocesses (in scope).

Example:

```
function a() {
 local export YACY_TIMEOUT=60
 yacy -r -d sth
 }
 export YACY_TIMEOUT=4
 echo "$YACY_TIMEOUT" # 4
 a
 echo "$YACY_TIMEOUT" # 4
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Variables are always available to sub-processes. In:

```
a=1
(echo "$a")
```

you see 1.

I think what you meant is that you want the variable to have a local scope and  be exported to the environment so that they are passed *as environment variables* to commands that are *executed*. The execution of a command is the thing that wipes the memory of a process (and the environment is a way to preserve some data across it), forking a child copies the entire memory so everything is preserved.

For that, you can use `local -x`:

```
a=(1 2)
f() {
  local -x a=3
  typeset -p a
  printenv a # printenv being *executed*
}
f
typeset -p a
```

gives:

```
typeset -x a=3
3
typeset -a a=( 1 2 )
```

Or you can `export` it after having been declared `local`:

```
a=(1 2)
f() {
  local a=3
  export a
  typeset -p a
  printenv a # printenv being *executed*
}
f
typeset -p a
```

Note that you can pass a variable in the environment of a single command without defining it otherwise as a shell variable with:

```
a=(1 2)
f() {
  a=3 printenv a # printenv being *executed*
}
f
typeset -p a
```

Note that `local` originated in the Almquist shell in the late 80s, but works differently from `zsh`'s. In the Almquist shell (and its descendants like dash and the sh of NetBSD/FreeBSD), `local` only affects the scope of a variable and doesn't change the value or attributes of a variable.

zsh's `local` works more like ksh93's `typeset` in that it declares a brand new variable that is independent from the one in the outer scope.

ksh88, bash and pdksh's `local`/`typeset` try to do that as well but still inherit some attributes from the variable of the outer scope including the *export* attribute. That changed in ksh93 though note that ksh93 also switched to static scoping and only implements local scope in functions declared with the `function f { ...; }` syntax.

Comment: `export a=1 ; f() { local a=3 ; export a ; printenv a ; } ; f ; printenv a #zsh` Yay!

Comment: instead of local and then export, you can do `local -x ...` to achieve the same thing

Answer (score 2):

Assuming that what you want to do is to give a process an environment variable with a value that may be different from the value of the shell variable with the same name that may be in scope in the shell at the point of invocation of the command:

```sh
a () {
    YACY_TIMEOUT=60 yacy -r -d std
}
```

This is the standard syntax for running a command and giving it a particular value of an environment variable.  The variable `YACY_TIMEOUT`, if it exists in the same scope as the body of the `a` function, would not be modified.

This would work in any POSIX shell.

What this does *not* do is to allow you to use `YACY_TIMEOUT` with the "local" value inside the function before calling `yacy`.

In `zsh` or any other shell that supports local variables declared with `local`, you could do

```bash
a () {
    local YACY_TIMEOUT=60

    YACY_TIMEOUT=$YACY_TIMEOUT yacy -r -d sth
}
```

Here, `YACY_TIMEOUT` would be local to the `a` function.  The injection of the variable as an environment variable in the `yacy` process happens as in the first example I gave, by preceding the invocation by an assignment.

Now `YACY_TIMEOUT` is both local and is also available in the `yacy` process' environment.  This would work in any shell that supports using `local` to declare local variables.

Comment: This necessates having code written in a specialized manner. The subshell solution works with any code, including code that we can not modify.

Comment: @HappyFace What part of the code are you not able to modify?  Also note that I'm not doing anything "special" here, and  that the second piece of code is not very different from your own proposal.

Answer (score 1):

Use a subshell:

```
function a() (
 export YACY_TIMEOUT=60
 yacy -r -d sth
)
```

Example:

```
% a () ( TIMEOUT=60; env | grep TIMEOUT )
% export TIMEOUT=4
% echo $TIMEOUT
4
% a
TIMEOUT=60
% echo $TIMEOUT
4
```